# How can I separate a .txt file into data values for graphing?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib to graph data from a .txt file.
Here is a sample txt file:

```
{Time:2020-07-02T09:27:54.640 SCM:{ID: 3841216 Type: 5 Tamper:{Phy:01 Enc:01} Consumption: 8822532 CRC:0xAE6D}} {Time:2020-07-02T09:28:29.660 SCM:{ID: 1649214 Type: 5 Tamper:{Phy:00 Enc:03} Consumption: 4660959 CRC:0x3B40}} {Time:2020-07-02T09:29:31.170 SCM:{ID: 1649214 Type: 5 Tamper:{Phy:00 Enc:03} Consumption: 4660960 CRC:0x6BCD}}
```

I am unsure on how to change the x and y coordinates.
Here is the code I have:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
with open('test2.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]
    y = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]



plt.show()
```

I copied this from another post "How can you plot data from a .txt file using matplotlib?"  I'm not sure what `x = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]` does exactly, so any guidance would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line.split()` breaks the string into an array of strings, "splitting" on whitespace (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for more details).  In this case, it is being used in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  Therefore, `[line.split()[0] for line in lines]` creates a an array of strings, which are chosen as the first contiguous sequence of non-whitespace characters from each line.  Given the example text you've given us, this means that `x` and `y` would both be equal to `['{Time:2020-07-02T09:27:54.640']`

I can't really see how this will accomplish anything.  However, I thought it would be fun so I made up some details and turned it into an exercise, hope it helps you.

I'm going to assume that you have a text file with lines similar to the one sample line you've given us.  The, I'm going to parse this file into a python data structure (an array of `dict`s).  Then I'm going to take the `Time` and `SCM.consumption` fields and plot them with `matplotlib`.

Here's the code.

```
# parse_to_json.py

from pprint import pprint

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set to true to see debug information if the parser isn't working.
DEBUG = False

# Decorator factory used to help develop the parser
def print_debug_info(print_result=False):
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped(txt,i):
            if DEBUG:
                print(f'{f.__name__:15} {i:3} {txt[i:i+5]}')
            result = f(txt,i)
            if DEBUG and print_result:
                print(' '*20 + str(result))
            return result
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

# 
# A very basic parser.
#

@print_debug_info()
def eat_ws(txt,i):
    """return index of next non-whitespace character"""
    while i < len(txt) and txt[i].isspace(): 
        i += 1
    return i

@print_debug_info()
def parse_obj(txt,i):
    """parse an object: { [kv]* } """
    obj = dict()
    while txt[i] != '}':
        k,v,i = parse_kv(txt,i)
        obj[k] = v
    return obj,eat_ws(txt,i+1)

@print_debug_info(True)
def parse_key(txt,i):
    """parse a key: [^:]*: """
    k = ''
    while txt[i] != ':':
        k += txt[i]
        i += 1
    return k,eat_ws(txt,i+1)

@print_debug_info(True)
def parse_value(txt,i):
    """parse a value: [obj, [^ {]* """
    if txt[i] == '{':
        return parse_obj(txt,eat_ws(txt,i+1))
    else:
        v = ''
        while txt[i] not in [' ','}']:
            v += txt[i]
            i += 1
        return v,eat_ws(txt,i)

@print_debug_info(True)
def parse_kv(txt,i):
    """parse a key:value pair """
    k,i = parse_key(txt,i)
    v,i = parse_value(txt,i)
    return k,v,eat_ws(txt,i)

def parse_string(txt):
    """entry into the parser, parse the whole string"""
    i = eat_ws(txt,0)
    objs = []
    while i < len(txt):
        v,i = parse_value(txt,i)
        objs.append(v)
    return objs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('info.txt') as f:
        text = f.read()
    objs = parse_string(text)
    # Pretty print the objects we've parsed
    pprint(objs)
    # collect times using the datetime64 numpy datatype
    times = [np.datetime64(obj['Time']) for obj in objs]
    # collect the consumption values
    consumption = [int(obj['SCM']['Consumption']) for obj in objs]
    # plot with matplotlib
    plt.plot(times,consumption)
    plt.show()
```